# How to make the function loop through the Array

Tags: javascript, function, destructuring

Having this Array of Objects:

```
let myFriends = [
  { title: "Osama", age: 39, available: true, skills: ["HTML", "CSS"] },
  { title: "Ahmed", age: 25, available: false, skills: ["Python", "Django"] },
  { title: "Sayed", age: 33, available: true, skills: ["PHP", "Laravel"] },
];
```

And this Variable:
`let chosen = 2;`

I need to Destruct it depending on the `chosen` variable to get something like this:

```
// If chosen === 1

"Osama"
39
"Available"
"CSS"

// If chosen === 2

"Ahmed"
25
"Not Available"
"Django"

// If chosen === 3

"Sayed"
33
"Available"
"Laravel"
```

I Tried this code:

```
switch (chosen) {
  case 1:
    const { title: t1, age: a1, available: av1, skills: s1 } = myFriends[0];
    const [h1, c1] = myFriends[0].skills
    console.log(t1)
    console.log(a1)
    console.log(av1 ? "Available" : "Not Available")
    console.log(c1)
    break;
  case 2:
    const { title: t2, age: a2, available: av2, skills: s2 } = myFriends[1];
    const [h2, c2] = myFriends[1].skills
    console.log(t2)
    console.log(a2)
    console.log(av2 ? "Available" : "Not Available")
    console.log(c2)
    break;
  case 3:
    const { title: t3, age: a3, available: av3, skills: s3 } = myFriends[2];
    const [h3, c3] = myFriends[2].skills
    console.log(t3)
    console.log(a3)
    console.log(av3 ? "Available" : "Not Available")
    console.log(c3)
}
```

And it works, but I want to make a simpler code. So I tried this one:

```
function chosenPerson(chosen) {
  const { title: t, age: a, available: av, skills: s } = myFriends[`${chosen}`];
  const [h, c] = myFriends[`${chosen}`].skills
  console.log(t)
  console.log(a)
  console.log(av ? "Available" : "Not Available")
  console.log(c)
};

chosenPerson();
```

It didn't work, so how can i make the function change with the `chosen` variable

Comment: You're overthinking this. `myFriends[chosen - 1]` contains the object you need, then it should be easy to just get the values from the object. Notice, that you don't have to extract values from the properties to variables, just use dot notation to access those when printing.

Comment: Like this (JS arrays start at 0) `const showFriend = idx => Object.entries(myFriends[idx]).map(([key,value]) => console.log(key,':',Array.isArray(value) ? value[1] : value)); showFriend(1)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want `myFriends[\`${chosen}\`]`  to change with the change of chosen, so the index changes and the data destructured change as well.
is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You've to pass `chosen` when calling the function. Evaluating variables doesn't need any special tricks, just use their names to represent the value in variables (see my first comment). Like mpungjan said, array indexing is zero-based, that's why you need `chosen - 1`, as the range of the said variable seems to start from 1, alternatively start it from zero, then you can drop `- 1` from the index.

Comment: @Teemu You are right about the `chosen - 1` i missed this part, but the problem was that I didn't pass the `chosen` variable to the function call. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Teemu the problem was that I didn't pass `chosen` to the function call.
and there is no need to use this `myFriends['${chosen}']`.

all I needed were `myFriends[chosen - 1]` as the array is 0 based index, and to pass `chosen` to the function call like this `chosenPerson(chosen)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myFriends = [
  { title: "Osama", age: 39, available: true, skills: ["HTML", "CSS"] },
  { title: "Ahmed", age: 25, available: false, skills: ["Python", "Django"] },
  { title: "Sayed", age: 33, available: true, skills: ["PHP", "Laravel"] },
];

let choosen = 2;
function getDetail(option){
  const {title, age, available, skills } = myFriends[option -1];
  
  return [title, age, available ? "Available" : "Non Available" , skills.join(',')]
}

console.log(getDetail(choosen));
```

Try this solution which return output inside an array
I hope this will fix your problem.